# Traduction du mot grec « kalaísthitos »

Tags: traduction, usage, synonymes, grec, antonyme

Je me demande comment rendre en français le mot grec *[kalaísthitos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%AF%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%82)* et les mot (substantif) de la même famille *[kalaisthisía](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B1#Greek)* ainsi que les contraires, respectivement, *[akalaísthitos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%AF%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%82#Greek)* et *[akalaisthisía](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B1#Greek)*.

Voici quelques mots possibles auxquels je pense ainsi que des antonymes :

> élégant, élégance - inélégant, inélégance
>
> bon goût - mauvais goût/absence de goût/manque de goût
>
> esthétique - non esthétique
>
> raffiné - non raffiné
>
> charmant - non charmant

Je me demande si l'on peut les utiliser interchangeablement (e.g. bon goût et esthétique, inélégant et manque de goût, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le Wiktionary indique que ce mot a deux sens différents. Le plus sage est donc de supposer que chacun de ses sens pourra se traduire différemment dans un autre langue, qui plus est en fonction du contexte.

Tous les mots présentés ont des points en commun mais ne pourront pas être interchangeables quelle que soit la phrase.

On peut par exemple être élégant et avoir néanmoins mauvais goût...

La chirurgie esthétique ne peut pas s'appeler chirurgie charmante, raffinée, de bon goût ou élégante.

« Un homme élégant » se dit, « un homme esthétique » pas vraiment.